# Передача типов с интерфейсом в параметры метода расширения C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Долго бился над этим вопросом, штудируя литературу и неистово насилуя гугл, но так и не нашел решения, может кто здесь подскажет.

Начну с самого начала. У меня есть три класса, которые реализуют свойства одного и того же интерфейса:

```
interface IStandartUnit
{
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Классы приводить не буду полностью (много конфиденциальной информации, да и не нужна она здесь):

```
public class UnitDepartment : IStandartUnit //подразделения
public class UnitFilial : IStandartUnit //филиалы
public class UnitPerson : IStandartUnit //сотрудники
```

Для отображения списка по каждому из классов использую *CheckedListBox* (почему? - лирика, к делу не особо относящаяся.). В процессе выполнения возникла необходимость в создании метода расширения для *CheckedListBox* дабы по переданному *ID* вычислять индекс элемента в списке. Например, вот так:

```
public static class ListBoxExtension
{
    public static int GetUnitIndexById(this CheckedListBox clb, int _id)
    {
        int i = 0;

        foreach(UnitFilial uf in clb.Items)
        {
            if (uf.ID == _id)
            {
                break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

Вообще, в результате должно получиться следующее: я передаю *ID* и *bool-состояние* в метод расширения для *CheckedListBox* и метод меняет свойство *Checked* у элемента списка на переданное. Но я решил начать с простого подхода, просто ища индекс.
Сложность вот в чем: мне необходим универсальный метод расширения для списков всех трех классов. Кто еще не понял - я использую классы добавляя их экземпляры в *CheckedListBox* (ToString() прописан в каждом классе, не волнуйтесь =Р). Не смешивая. Один список - один класс.

**Итоговый вопрос. Могу ли я каким то образом реализовать нечто вроде этого чтобы оно работало:**

```
public static class ListBoxExtension
{
    public static void SetUnitState(this CheckedListBox clb, int _id, bool _state)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(IStandartUnit su in clb.Items)
        {
            if(su.ID == _id)
            {
                break;
            }
            i++;    
        }
        clb.SetItemChecked(i, _state);
    }
}
```

Буду рад любым советам, касающимся дела. Спасибо.

*UPD: Прошу прощения за то что отнял ваше время. Код работает как должен. Это я просто тупенький. Надеюсь, что инфа в вопросе не будет бесполезной, авось кому-то да пригодится.*

Comment: А в чем проблема указанного в конце кода? На первый взгляд должно работать

Comment: `int i = clb.Items.Cast<object>().Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Item = x as IStandartUnit }).Where(x => x.Item != null).First(x => x.Item.ID == _id).Index;`

Comment: Точно, то, что LINQ не только для общения с БД можно юзать у меня как то из головы вылетело... спасибо. Должно упростить задачу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оно так и работает:

```
public static class ListBoxExtension
{
    public static void SetUnitState(this CheckedListBox clb, int _id, bool _state)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach(IStandartUnit su in clb.Items)
        {
            if(su.ID == _id)
            {
                break;
            }
            i++;    
        }
        clb.SetItemChecked(i, _state);
    }
}
```